# azure ad b2c run user flow doesnt return token with claims on it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured a user flow to get the users email surname given name and city, and when I press Run User Flow and add the callback URL to be jwt.ms, I dont see the email and all of the above claims on the token. Why?

Comment: To which Identity provider are you connecting the user flow?  is the account you are testing with is local B2C account, or a social account?

Comment: It is a local B2C account but the claims I request are collected when a user registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked needed claims when I run user flow.

Before that make sure to add the required API permissions like **openid , offline_access,profile, and User.Read.All** permissions granted admin consent:

[image]

When I run the signin userflow or signupsignin but the user is already signed in , the output claims  when user logged in did not contain any additional claims.

As I had only below claims selected to return in user flow application claims:

[image]

[image]

When I signed up with the extra application claims selected .

[image]

```
https://xxxb2c.b2clogin.com/xxxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_newSignupSignin&client_id=5xxxxxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

And when the new user registers , and when he filles everything .

[image]
[image]

And the claims appeared in the token:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any pointer I can search for why the scopes dont get returned?

Comment: I will ask a separate question